# GridBagLayout Jbutton Position

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

This is what I have :

[image]

and this is what I want to have :

[image]

Here's a piece of my code

```
container.add(conteneur2 , BorderLayout.EAST);


conteneur2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


conteneur2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

JButton Bouton= new JButton("New remote site");

// Bouton 1 

gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.gridheight = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

conteneur2.add(bouton,gbc);
```

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the anchor `NORTH`

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
```

and the y weight to 1 means all the free space is distributed in y direction.

```
gbc.weighty = 1;
```

Comment: thanx !! another question : if i want to do something like this (add another buttons under the first buttons )  what i have de change :   http://hpics.li/babe338

Comment: What do you mean? Adding another button under the first one?

Comment: yeah  i know i have to make gbc.gridx = 0; and gbc.gridy=1 ; but what else ?

Comment: Thats true and additional you need to set weighty=0 for the first and weighty=1 for the second button then.

Comment: that doesn't work look this is my code : http://hpics.li/405b31d                             and this is the result : http://hpics.li/9ecaf76

Comment: I wrote weighty = 0 for the FIRST (UPPER) button and weighty=1 for the SECOND (UNDER) button.

Comment: I really don't get the Weighty thing :(   i want to do this : http://hpics.li/0bf953d

Comment: All buttons should have weighty=0 (which is default so could also leave out this attribute). But the very last button needs weighty=1 to specify that the rest space in y direction is not used means all buttons get pushed up (to their anchor)